# send a language document after phd interview?

Tags: graduate-admissions, language-exams

I did the PhD interview two weeks ago, and in the application before I mentioned French as a language I speak, but in the interview they only tested another language, and in the application, I didn't include the language certificate, as it is not required, but I nevertheless had it available, now can I send it to the committee after the interview? It might say something.

Comment: Why do you think it might be necessary or even useful to do this?

Comment: Ok, it might work to my advantage if someone else provided it or provided a lower level

Comment: Unless you are seeking a PhD in a French-speaking country or your research area is directly related to French, I'm sure nobody cares about it.

Comment: My research area is related to French, my point is that how it would be perceived after two weeks after the intevriew?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a lot of competition I would say that if it were the deciding factor they would ask for it. You can of course send a brief email to state that you realised that it might be relevant and you would be happy to provide your certificate if needed.